# how to throw url from component then set it as new service url?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi im new in angular i would like to pass url from component then set it as new service url. this is my code

pokemon.service.ts

```
  private _url: string = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon";

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  setUrl(value: string){
    this._url = value;
  }

  getUrl(): Observable<IPokemon[]>{
    return this.http.get<IPokemon[]>(this._url);
  }
```

pokemon-search.component.ts

```
export class PokemonSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  pokemons: any = [];
  pokemonUrl: string;

  constructor(private _pokemons : PokemonsService ) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this._pokemons.getUrl().subscribe(data => {
      this.pokemons = data;
    });
  }

  previousPokemon(url){
    this._pokemons.setUrl(url);
  }
}
```

i throw the url back to the service but it doesnt change the output of the default url. please help me thank you so much!

Comment: when you are calling this?

Comment: clearify your question what you are asking not understand

Comment: You need to ` this._pokemons.setUrl(url)` before subscribing. In your case, you have already subscribed in `OnInit` .YOu need to provide more code to help us understand the exact use case.

Answer (score 0):

you can subscribe to it after updating the url to get the updated data

```
previousPokemon(url){
    this._pokemons.setUrl(url);
    this._pokemons.getUrl().subscribe(data => {
      this.pokemons = data;
    });
  }
```